# Is there an in-world-explanation for why some items can’t be collected?

Tags: treasure

I quite often play with newcomers, which I indeed enjoy. But I always struggle with their first kill.

Player: "Hey, that guard had a lot of armor, a sword, and a horse. I take all of those."
Game Master: "Well, actually you can have (*roll dice*) a few coins, otherwise you’d get rich in 10 minutes killing random people."

What in-world explanation is there for why some stuff can’t be collected, while other stuff can?

Comment: It depends entirely on the world, doesn't it? Do you have a specific system in mind?

Comment: Knowing the system would definitely help.

Answer (score 6):

There is no in-world explanation for why not. Saying “no you can't pick that up” for an out-of-game reason is by definition an out-of-game reason. That's fine to do, but if you're going to apply [video-game logic to loot](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/MoneySpider), you should make it clear that the world doesn't behave in an intuitive way and that's just how loot is going to work. Don't angst about it, don't fret — just be up-front that you don't want to deal with the natural consequences of looting equipment, and ask the player to suspend their disbelief for the sake of balance or whatever.

If you don't like having your world be nonsensical like that, but you still want to keep their hands off obvious loot, as it seems from asking a question about how to justify this stuff in-world… you can't. Don't bother. Relax your grip on the treasure and just let the player's character interact with a fallen foe's equipment just like any other thing they discover inside the game reality.

If you don't want a nonsensical world, *just let them take things*, and then you can figure out what **consequences** (if any) result from their actions.

- They take armor, sword, and horse of a guard patrolling the roads? Those aren't fungible commodities, those are identifiable. Now they have to either find someone who will buy what is obviously the goods of a dead guard from TownNameHere, or learn the hard way that robbery and murder are frowned upon when they naively flash them around town or try to sell them to a merchant who can tell where those things came from.
- They take the armor, sword, and horse of a guard in the Evil Castle of The Dark Villain? Great, they probably won't have to worry about anyone caring where this equipment came from, but that's not the only consequence possible. They've got to carry that stuff, and they've got to feed the horse, and if you're making those easy to do — well, don't. Horses are a pain to take care of, and carrying not only all your own gear but all the gear of a whole other person is quite encumbering.
- They take the armor, sword, and horse of a guard that nobody cares about, and they have the means to pack the gear and care for the horse? Then it's not a problem. **Let the player enjoy the spoils of their victory.** Taking away what they've achieved is not a great plan for making newcomers welcome. If they can do all those things, they're prepared to accomplish this, and it's disempowering to take it away. So you have to now deal with their increased wealth and resources — so what? Players deal with unexpected situations all the time — be like a player and roll with it. Figure out how the world will change and how it will treat the player character differently now, and do that instead of trying to keep them within whatever role you've pre-determined for them.

In short: let the player's character take stuff they've earned, let that stuff have real impacts on their future for good and/or ill, and roll with the unexpected development. You get to have the internally-consistent world you seem to want, and they get to keep their accomplishments — everyone wins.

Comment: very good answer and true for any system out there

Answer (score 3):

**Let them loot it.**

There's no reason the players shouldn't be able to loot gear from enemies they kill. It's just that, generally, there's not much point.

In most cases (in D&D) the players will already have better gear, which they picked up for chump change. Nobody is going to buy some goblin's homemade, bloodstained armor & bow. If it's worse than the gear you have, and you can't sell it, why bother lugging it around. Sure you *can* loot it, but what would you *do* with it?

If the gear is better than what the party has, or at least good enough that it might conceivably be worth something, then other problems arise. Weapons & armor may be the wrong size or the wrong type to be useful for anyone in the party. High-end gear may have distinctive markings, which could lead to awkward questions when using or selling it depending on how it was acquired ("Man, did you hear the king was assassinated yesterday? Crazy, right? Anyways, I just happen to have found this lovely sword with the royal crest on it laying around, how much would you be willing to buy it for?").

Answer (score 2):

Well in my games all the items that the killed enemy had are obtainable. I think something that balances this is that we face mostly kobolds weak armed enemies and other misc. enemies with minimal gear. Fully geared guards should come with a fairly strong challenge. The guards should also have a fair amount of backup (or even unlimited if they are in a major city). In short just try putting the group in fighting situations early where they cant get that much gear or gold. If this is a problem with your group and they try to push for stronger enemies, make kobolds with kobold sized and shaped armor. This makes a fair challenge without giving them hugely valuable goods. Carrying capacity is also a thing.

Answer (score 0):

It depends a lot on both the setting and the system you are playing. However, in the example you gave, the guard's gear might well be marked in a particular way, or bearing a particular set of identifying colours, which would mean nobody wants to purchase them for fear of being arrested. Or, the gear could be poor quality, and/or poorly maintained, meaning the group might well have to sell the gear just to make that small number of coins in the randomly determined treasure.

The same could apply in a higher-tech setting - although criminals might have a small market for police uniforms, who else would buy them? And those guns, that the bad guys never cleaned? Might be useful to a scrap merchant, maybe.

A number of groups I've played in also tend to gloss over this sort of stuff, unless it is actually worth a decent amount of money (i.e. in D&D3.x, masterwork or magical items only).